# Graphic novel about a man and a dog talking about philosophical topics and going on adventures

Tags: identification-request

I read this graphic novel a few years ago when I was in elementary school, I remember very little of it so it might be difficult.

The book is a collection of individual comics, the stories in each small comic are mostly unrelated to the other ones. The main character is man and his dog. In each comic, they seem to be in different places, some of the places seem normal-ish, some are other-worldly and some are almost surreal. The man and his dog often talk about **philosophical** questions together, related or unrelated to the scene they are in.

These are the things I'm sure of, other details I remember are likely incorrect, take them with multiple grains of salt:

1. The main character wears something on his head? A cap? A hat? A hoodie?
2. The title of the book might be the name of the dog or the man.
3. There might have been a girl trapped in a bubble of some sorts in one of the places the man went to, and the man might have fell in love with her?
4. The art style might have been smooth, the drawing of the man is kinda plump and short.

EDIT: The name of the man might be Cooper?????

Comment: doesn't fit, mostly, but have you ruled out calvin and hobbes?

Comment: @Yorik Yes I have, I have also asked chatGPT about this and it couldn't figure out the book either, so I thought it might have been really obscure. Using chatGPT, I have also ruled out "Bone", "Tintin", "Sandman" and a ton of other ones.

Comment: Copper by Kazu Kibuishi?

Comment: @Ayshe OH MY GOD YES that's the one!! Thank you!!

Comment: @DaNubCoding: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Self-answers can't be accepted until 48 hours after they were asked, I think only 5-10 minutes for answers by others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is *[Copper](https://www.boltcityproductions.com/copper)* by Kazu Kibuishi, a comic first published in *YOLK*, an Asian-American culture magazine, and later continued online, and then [released in book format](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0545098939).

[image: Front cover of the hardback book release]

> Copper is a webcomic I started shortly after the terrorist attacks on the World Trade Center in New York City on September 11th, 2001. I drew a picture of a scared, quiet, but calm kid, and I decided to write a story about him and his fearful dog, Fred. Scroll down to the bottom to read the very first Copper comic, “Rocket Pack Fantasy”.

Thank you Ayshe :)

Comment: Hi. If @Ayshe helped you with the answer, it's generally the done thing to let them post it and then accept it.

Comment: @MattThrower: Eh, better to have an answer in the system than a comment answer that might disappear, and 6 hours is a pretty generous time period to allow for Ayshe to post their answer.

Comment: That said, if Ayshe does post a good answer, I will gladly upvote them as well.